# Using random with strings in java ?

Tags: java, random

I am trying to choose a string out of 4 strings randomly, and to show this string on the console. How can i do it ? For example, there is a question, if user answers it correctly, then the console will display one of the strings that i chose. I know how to choose an integer value randomly, but i could not figure out how to choose a string randomly. Please Help?

Comment: You need to post what you have tried

Answer (score 9):

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomSelect {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

         String [] arr = {"A", "B", "C", "D"};
         Random random = new Random();

         // randomly selects an index from the arr
         int select = random.nextInt(arr.length); 

         // prints out the value at the randomly selected index
         System.out.println("Random String selected: " + arr[select]); 
    }
}
```

Using charAt:

```
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomSelect {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

         String text = "Hello World";
         Random random = new Random();

         // randomly selects an index from the arr
         int select = random.nextInt(text.length()); 

         // prints out the value at the randomly selected index
         System.out.println("Random char selected: " + text.charAt(select)); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, How can i do this using indexOf() ?

Comment: I updated the answer to randomly select a character from a String. what do you want to use indexOf() for? indexOf() is used to locate a substring within a string.

Answer (score 5):

1. Put your strings in an array.
2. Then get a random integer from the `Random` class that's within the bounds of the length of your array (look at the modulo `%` operator to figure out how to do this; alternatively, constrain the call to random.nextInt() by passing an uppper bound).
3. Get the string by indexing into the array with the number you just got.

Answer (score 3):

```
String[] s = {"your", "array", "of", "strings"};

Random ran = new Random();
String s_ran = s[ran.nextInt(s.length)];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Random r = new Random();
System.out.println(list.get(r.nextInt(list.size())));
```

this will generate a random number between 0 [inclusive] and list.size() [non-inclusive].
Then, just get that element at that index out of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use that integer value that you select randomly as the index for your array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

> shuffle(List list) 
>             Randomly permutes the specified list using a default source of randomness.

```
// Create a list
List list = new ArrayList();

// Add elements to list
..

// Shuffle the elements in the list
Collections.shuffle(list);
list.get(0);
```

Comment: While technically it solves the problem, but this is probably the least efficient way of doing it.  see my answer below

Comment: You are right, but for something like this, which I'm sure is a homework, I just wanted to give an alternative way.