# Randomising strings in an array(Java)

Tags: java, arrays, string

How to generate random words from an array of strings? e.g.

```
String [] randWords = {"ant","bat","cat","do"};
```

I know the math.Random method and Random class operate on int,boolean and float values and i'm guessing i'll need the array index in my implementation.

How should I approach such a problem?

Comment: random words with meaning? or just random permutations of the words? please provide an output example.

Comment: `randWords[rand.nextInt(randWords.length)];`

Comment: Have a look at `Arrays.asList` and `Collections.shuffle`...

Comment: @amit just the display random words without their meaning

Comment: @Anirban and Jon,  i will take a look at them now thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public final class SessionIdentifierGenerator {
    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public String nextSessionId() {
        return new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks guys! found the solution in the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918350/using-random-with-strings-in-java (above)